# why are my collectionViewCell's displaying unusual behavior?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

For some reason, my collectionViewCell's are unrecognized when they are selected. It's not until another cell is touched afterwards that the previous cell is recognized. To explain how I realized this, I added the following code to my collectionView's `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` method: `println("user tapped on cell # \(indexPath.row)")`. When I run the app and select a cell, my console doesn't respond until I tap another cell, then it reads the `println` I added. For instance, if I select the first cell, the debugger doesn't print anything until i select another cell, then the console reads "`user tapped on thumbnail # 0`".

Now I've added an animation to my collectionView that enlarges each cell on selection, so this is how I know it isn't an indexPath issue because the cell indexPath # that is printed in the console is the correct cell that is enlarged in the view, but like i said, the cell isn't animated on its selection, not until i select another cell afterwards.

Here is my collectionView delegate and dataSource logic:

```
 // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.books.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        let book = self.books[indexPath.row]
        let coverImage = book.coverImage
        if coverImage == nil {
            book.fetchCoverImage({ (image, error) -> Void in
                if self.collectionView != nil {

                    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
                }
            })
        } else {
            let imageView = cell.imageView
            imageView.image = book.coverImage
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        let book = self.books[indexPath.row]

        self.selectedImageView = cell.imageView

        if !isModeModal {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController

            controller.imageSelected = book.coverImage

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

        }

        println("user tapped on thumbnail # \(indexPath.row)")

    }
}
```

Why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: Look carefully at the name of the method you have implemented did**De**selectItemAtIndexPath` - You want `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: oh gosh, this is embarrasing haha @Paulw11how could have missed that

Comment: The risks of autocompletion...

Comment: EXACTLY haha @Paulw11

Comment: We've all been there.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't run your code, but I think, that the problem could be caused by `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`. Try to use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` instead.

If necessary you can add `deselectItemAtIndexPath` :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath, animated: Bool)
```

}

Comment: oh gosh, i just realized it was didDeselectItemAtIndexPath by accident :(((((((((..